# Yii2 working with private property - non db column

Tags: properties, yii2

I am working with Yii2 and till date using public property for non db columns like following :

```
public $category_id;
public function rules() {
        return [
            [['category_id'], 'safe'],           
        ];
    }
//// inside $dataProvider
$this->load($params);
```

it works perfectly. but now I want to make category_id as private so how to manage it inside rules and how to load and also set inside form element on load ?

Comment: Why do you want to make it private?

Answer (score 0):

You may use accessor and mutator for access to your private attribute, for example:

```
private category_id;

public function setCategory (value)
{
    $this->category_id = value;
}

public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category_id;
}
```

These methods allow to use private attribute just as public attribute with different name in other parts of application. For example,  you may use it in rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [['category', 'safe']];
 }
```

Or in another code:

```
$model->category = 777
```

Comment: but inside dataProvider how to load data for them ? and how to add validation rules for them ?

Comment: I was added the additional information to my answer